# Custom UIButton inside a UITableView keeps highlighted after being pressed

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uibutton

I have implemented a custom UIButton, posted in cocoacontrols.com:

http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/imageless-gradient-buttons

I´ve just converted the project to ARC and setted up the buttons. They work, but after being pressed once, they keep they highlighted gradient.

To set them up, I just changed the class on both storyboard and on the IBOutlets and I´ve selected the gradient I wante on viewDidLoad.

Any idea on what could be the problem?

**EDIT**: I've been spending more time with it and it appears to be that the problem only happens when the button is on a UITableView. It works OK when it is on a UIViewController

**EDIT #2**: according to the NSLogs, when the container is a UIViewController, the gradient is back to normal when a button is pressed:

```
2012-05-26 10:53:17.950 GradientButtons[11507:f803] highlighthed
2012-05-26 10:53:18.040 GradientButtons[11507:f803] highlighthed
2012-05-26 10:53:18.140 GradientButtons[11507:f803] Normal
```

but when the container is a UTableViewController, the button remains with the highligthed gradient:

```
2012-05-26 10:55:20.969 GradientButtons[11507:f803] highlighthed
2012-05-26 10:55:21.069 GradientButtons[11507:f803] highlighthed
```

I've checked the viewContentMode and it is all the same for all the buttons, UIView and UITableView (Scale to Fill). Changing it to redraw doesn't change behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the check responsible for normal/highlighted gradient drawing:

```
   if (self.state == UIControlStateHighlighted)
        gradient = self.highlightGradient;
    else
        gradient = self.normalGradient;
```

You need to set the breakpoint or add NSLog's to see whether the normal gradient is selected there. If it doesn't, the next step would be to override the normal UIButton  `drawRect` adding the state log. Use it instead of the colored buttons to see whether that's a standard UIButton behavior for your table (e.g. you might keep the cell highlighted after the button is clicked which forces the subviews also to be highlighted)

---

Based on your log i found it interesting an reproduced the problem, it seems to be a race condition for the highlighted state to be caught at `touchesEnded` (try to hold a click for about a second - the state will be `normal` at `touchesEnded`). The reason needs to be investigated further, as a workaround you could use the following code:

```
-(void) setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted
{
    NSLog(@"setHighlighted %@", highlighted ? @"Y": @"N");
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: I've added the NSLogs. Apparently when the button is on a tableView, it doesn't go back to normal after being pressed.

Comment: I shall try that asap. However, more than anything else, I'd really like to know why only happens in tableviews. I've done a custom keypad using this buttons as reference. Curious enough, when the custom keypad is called on a tableview, it behaves very normal. No problem at all...

Comment: @Marcal now when you mentioned it again and i have a sample project to test, i can confirm the same problem adding a button on root UIView rather than on a tableView cell. It must be a problem of the subclassing implementation, i can't see anything wrong at the proposed workaround until you want to override `setNeedsDisplay` and change `highlighted` there. However, there might be other related problems, i'd also like to understand the source of the problem to solve it in a better way.

Comment: The workaround works nicely, thanks a lot. I would be nice, however to find out where this issue comes from. Thanks again!